# Screen Freezing when Setting Multiple Roots

Tags: aurelia

When my aurelia app starts I send them first to the login page and check and see if they are logged in and if so, set set the root to app, otherwise, have them log in.

```
 aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("modules/login")));
```

This should work, according to everything I could find.  It does actually set the root to as far as the code is concerned as I see activity in the console, but the html on the screen never moves from the login screen.  Even typing something manually in the address bar does not change the html. So it seems the router has stopped functioning. No errors are logged in the console.

```
import { AuthenticateStep, AuthService } from 'aurelia-authentication';
import { Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import { autoinject, PLATFORM, Aurelia } from "aurelia-framework";

@autoinject()
export class Login {

    constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private aurelia:Aurelia) {
            console.log("Starting Login...")
    }

    activate() {
        if (this.authService.authenticated) {
            console.log("is authenticate")
            this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false });

            console.log("setting root to 'app'");
            this.aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app"));


        }
        else {
            console.log("not auth");
        }
    }
}
```

In app.ts

```
activate() {
  console.log("app.activate");
  ...
```

}

[image: This is the console]

Is there something else I should be doing?

I have tried: https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/400

And this: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/07/aurelia-routing-switching-root-using-setroot/

Comment: Is the `activate` method you're showing the App or is it another page? Could you share your `App` and full console output? What happens if you put a breakpoint in the constructor / bind / attached / activate of `App`, do any of them get hit after `setRoot`?

Comment: It is from the Login Page.  I added the full class. I took a screenshot of the console which shows that the app does get set to root after the authentication is checked.  The issue is that the Login Page continues to show, like it is frozen on that page and will not navigate after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you can try:

- Chain the promises (make sure the navigation is done before you tell aurelia to switch the root)

  ```
  this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false })
      then(() => this.aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app")));
  ```
- Resolve the promises (would be necessary if the router still has work to do after the current `activate` because that work would need to be aborted)

  ```
  return this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false })
      then(() => this.aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app")));
  ```
- Verify that the `AppRouter` is reconfigured after you switch root (breakpoint in `configureRouter`, you may need to manually `.reset()` the router is the `isConfigured` flag is somehow still true)

You could try a different approach altogether.

Personally when I need to switch root between a public and an authenticated shell, I just have a dedicated path prefix for either (or both) and in my `main` method I set the root to the correct `App` based on the current `window.location`.

Example (in `main`):

```
if (/\/public/.test(window.location.pathname)) {
  au.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("shell/public"));
} else if ((/\/admin/.test(window.location.pathname)) {
  au.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("shell/admin"));
} else {
  au.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("shell/app"));
}
```

Redirecting between these roots goes outside of the router, simply with `window.location.href = "..."`;

Although it's arguably a little hacky, the nice thing about the approach is that you'll always have a completely clean Aurelia state after switching, and thus less you potentially need to clean up after.

In the non-public roots, you try to grab the auth token from localStorage and simply kick the user back to `public` if there is none (or they don't have sufficient privileges).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I finally figured out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the root is quite easy, but there is a caveat:

Set it either in response to a user generated event, or in the attached event.

Attempting to set it in the activated event or constructor will result in the screen becoming frozen on the root screen.

This took me pretty much a day to figure out, so I thought I would pass it on.

Here is what worked for me: I created a "app-shell" which is set to the root by main.

In app-shell, I check whether or not the person is already logged in, and then I set the root depending on the results.

```
import { AuthenticateStep, AuthService } from 'aurelia-authentication';
import { AppRouter } from 'aurelia-router';
import { autoinject, PLATFORM, Aurelia } from "aurelia-framework";

@autoinject()
export class AppShell {

    constructor(private router: AppRouter, private authService: AuthService, private aurelia: Aurelia) {

    }

    attached() {
        this.setRoot();
    }

    setRoot() {
        this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false }); //Not actually needed here, but is if the router has already been configured.
        if (this.authService.authenticated) {
            this.aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app"));
        }
        else {
            this.aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("modules/login"));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The main reason why `attached()` is a "safe" place to do this is because that's the end of the component lifecycle. Both in the constructor and in activate, things still happen afterward (in parallel since setRoot is an async operation). Hence my suggestion to resolve the promise during an async hook such as `activate`